# VBA type question beginner

Tags: excel, vba

I'm a newbie and I'm trying to learn VBA and i got a question about this code:
(Sorry for any mistake in English, I'm not a native speaker)

```
Option Explicit

Type rPaciente  'matriz de pacientes
   CodPaciente As Long
   PriorPaciente As Long
   IntvChegDistr As String
   Par1 As Double
   Par2 As Double
   Par3 As Double
   Par4 As Double
   IntvCheg As Double
   InstCheg As Double
End Type
Public mPaciente() As rPaciente
Public glQtdPaciente As Long
```

What are these "things" between `Type` and `End Type`, are they cells of the range of my worksheet, cause I got columns like Par1,Par2,...,Par4 in my worksheet but I don't got columns named IntvCheg neither InstCheg. And what does the command `Public someting() As otherthing` means?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Things" between `Type` and `End Type` are members of the `rPaciente` type. They are not mapped to anything, they only describe the set of data this type is meant to contain.
Probably there is a routine somewhere that maps the cells on your sheet to members of this type by creating an instance of the type and copying values from the sheet to the member variables of the instance.

`Public someting() As otherthing` is an array of type `otherthing`. The declaration does not include the dimensions for the array, so before it can be used, you must `ReDim` it to something:

```
ReDim someting(1 to 10)
```

Answer (score 0):

The Type declaration simply declare a Visual Basic Type structure. Is something like (really simplified view) a `struct` in c++ or a class without methods in any labguage.

The instruction

```
Public mPaciente() As rPaciente
```

declare a dinamyc array of rPaciente objects that probably will be filled with every row inside your excel file.

The instruction

```
Public glQtdPaciente As Long
```

declare a variable of type `Long` with the name `glQtdPaciente`